Unable to execute notebook using nbconvert due to display()
I have this Jupyter notebook which produces a tabbed widget. It runs fine and the widget shows up in JupyterLab. The code is as follows.
test.ipynb
import pandas as pd
import ipywidgets as widgets
import plotly.express as px
from IPython.display import display

data = {'A': [1, 1],
        'B': [2, 3]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Create tabs with line plots for each DataFrame
tab_contents = []
for df in [df1,df2]:
    fig = px.line(df)
    output = widgets.Output()
    with output:
        display(fig)
    tab_contents.append(output)

# Create tabs
my_tabs = widgets.Tab(children=tab_contents)

# Set titles for the tabs
for i in range(len(tab_contents)):
    my_tabs.set_title(i, "Tab " + str(i))

display(my_tabs)

My goal is to execute the notebook and ultimately convert it into a HTML document. I can run the notebook in JupyterLab when I click on "Restart Kernel and Run All Cells ...". However, I cannot execute the notebook using nbconvert.
jupyter nbconvert --to notebook --execute test.ipynb
The bash terminal (tried both Windows and WSL) is stuck at
[NbConvertApp] Converting notebook test.ipynb to notebook

I found that the problematic line is display(fig). I also tried using fig.show() but it still freezes. If I change that line to pass, I can then proceed and get the message
[NbConvertApp] Writing 9122 bytes to test.nbconvert.ipynb

What is going on here? How should I write a tab widget that can be executed and exported as HTML? My motivation is that I'm preparing a really long report, and using tabs can save me some vertical space. I'm new to Plotly so any advice to write this better would be appreciated.

There's several disconnects present in this post. "I'm new to Plotly so any advice to write this better would be appreciated." Plotly is only contributing to the plot that is making the content in each of the tabs. If the Plotly plots show in the notebook when you run it in the typical live way, then it isn't the Plotly plots. ipywidgets is contributing the tabs that you seem to be questioning the display of. "jupyter nbconvert --to notebook --execute test.ipynb" & " How should I write a tabbed widget that can be executed and exported as HTML?". Your jupyter nbconvert command isn't ....

 set up to sent the output to HTML and so you should do something like here. "I found that the problematic line is display(fig)." You are making interactive widgets and they need to have HTML to output too and be actively controlled. So you are in essence executing the notebook and it runs through to your widget and that is sitting there waiting for interaction. In summary: You may get it to work by changing your command; however, you may wish to see what I worked out here...

 and perhaps consider your example like there where a complex element is to be embedded in the exported HTML. I can look at it more in depth if you aren't finding any of the options I worked out there to be. Because that command to make HTML  is meant to be run as part of the code in the notebook you may still be able to use your  jupyter nbconvert as written in the post, without the -to html, but simply use the juoyter nbconvert to tirigger making running the notebook and let the notebook make the .html file.

Thanks @Wayne, I checked out your example and it produces the tabs in the HTML, which is exactly the behavior I want. However, I would like to convert the entire notebook into a HTML file, with the widget being part of it. This I'm not sure how to do it, but seeing your example makes me think that it is possible.

I know jupyter nbconvert has pre- & post- processors as part of it. I suspect these may help with this. I haven't looked into it lately in regards to  ipywidgets.

Update: I found that the code can run (with nbconvert) if I include a code block prior to it, but not sure why

Perhaps not a proper solution, but this code below worked for me and achieves what I wanted
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from ipywidgets import widgets
from IPython.display import display

data = {'A': [1, 1],
        'B': [2, 3]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)

tab_contents = []

for df in [df1,df2]:
    fig = px.line(df)
    graph = go.FigureWidget(fig)
    tab_contents.append(widgets.VBox([graph]))

my_tabs = widgets.Tab(children=tab_contents)

# Set titles for the tabs
for i in range(len(tab_contents)):
    my_tabs.set_title(i, "Tab " + str(i))

display(my_tabs)

